# Scale images inside divs with text

Tags: css, angular, sass, flexbox, angular-material

For a personal project with Angular, Angular Material and Flex-Layout I am trying to achieve a similar layout used by [Bring!](https://www.getbring.com/#!/app) App:
[image]

Having images of different size (not all squared) I would like to center them proportionally and allow some text under them.
I have the following template and scss styles:

```
<div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutGap="5px" class="cards-container">
 <div class="item-card">
   <div class="image">
     <img src="../../../../assets/icons/apple.png" alt="Mela" />
   </div>
   <span class="item-name">Mela</span>
   <span class="description">12</span>
 </div>
 <div class="item-card">
  <div class="image">
     <img src="../../../../assets/icons/milk.png" alt="Latte" />
  </div>
  <span class="item-name">Latte</span>
  <span class="description">1 description comes here, must be hidden if long text</span>
 </div>
</div>

//---------------------------------------------------

.cards-container {
  flex-wrap: wrap;

  .item-card {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-items: end;
    color: white;
    width: 7em;
    height: 7em;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: darkslategray;
    margin: 5px 0;
    img {
        width: 40%; // TODO: how to scale?
        height: 40%;
    }

    .text-container {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;

        .item-name {
            display: inline-block;
            font-size: 1.1em;
        }

        .description {
            width: 99%;
            font-size: 0.8em;
            text-align: center;
            overflow: hidden;
            white-space: nowrap;
            text-overflow: ellipsis;
            display: inline-block;
        }
    }
  }
}
```

However the images do not scale down to keep the proportions with the others images, especially if narrow and long.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], css issues are resolved quicker when we can actually try the code.

Comment: This is a side note but you wanna change your img path to this: `src="assets/icons/apple.png"` otherwise they will not be found in the prod build

Comment: Absolutely right mchl18, I am still testing locally, but I will fix it asap.

Answer (score 1):

It all seems to look fine but it looks like your HTML code is missing the `.text-container` div and class.

```
<div class="item-card">
   <div class="image">
     <img src="../../../../assets/icons/apple.png" alt="Mela" />
   </div>
   <span class="item-name">Mela</span>
   <span class="description">12</span>
 </div>
```

should be

```
<div class="item-card">
   <div class="image">
     <img src="../../../../assets/icons/apple.png" alt="Mela" />
   </div>
   <div class="text-container">
     <span class="item-name">Mela</span>
     <span class="description">12</span>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Now for the `text-overflow: ellipsis;` this doesn't work on multi-lines unless you implement some JavaScript or something.

If there is any change to your code, I'd make the images a `background-image` instead. There could be other ways without this, but it's what I use to make sure the container is responsive with the image always responsive and centred.

For Example: https://codepen.io/StudioKonKon/pen/wRjOzr (Includes SCSS)

```css
.image {
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  font-size: 0;
}
.image-mela {
  background-image: url("https://via.placeholder.com/150x175");
}
.image-latte {
  background-image: url("https://via.placeholder.com/200x50");
}
.image-long {
  background-image: url("https://via.placeholder.com/50x100");
}

.cards-container {
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.cards-container .item-card {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-items: end;
  color: white;
  width: 7em;
  height: 7em;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: darkslategray;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 0.5em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.cards-container .item-card .image {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  width: 40%;
  height: 40%;
}
.cards-container .item-card .text-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.cards-container .item-card .text-container .item-name {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
.cards-container .item-card .text-container .description {
  font-size: 0.8em;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutGap="5px" class="cards-container">
  <div class="item-card">
    <div class="image image-mela">Mela</div>
    <div class="text-container">
      <span class="item-name">Mela</span>
      <span class="description">12</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item-card">
    <div class="image image-latte">Latte</div>
    <div class="text-container">
      <span class="item-name">Latte</span>
      <span class="description">1 description comes here, must be hidden if long text</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item-card">
    <div class="image image-long">Long Image</div>
    <div class="text-container">
      <span class="item-name">Long Image Text</span>
      <span class="description">must be hidden if long text</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
   img {
        width: 40%; 
        height: auto;
    }
```

It should leave the image proportions consistent.

Comment: I tried, but leaving height:auto does not scale properly long images (eg. a bottle), compared to squared ones (eg. apple)

Answer (score 0):

It is simple. I think it will solve the problem. :)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>item</title>
    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
    .item-single{
        width: 100px;
        background-color: #e7e7e7;
        height: 100px;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .item-single span{
        display: block;
    border: 1px solid #000; /* just to show the alignment  */
    }
    .item-single img{
        width: 50%; /*  you can scale it down using width */
    border:1px solid #000; /* just to show the alignment */
        display: block;
        margin: auto;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="item-single">
        <img src="http://sugamparajuli.com.np/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/banana.png">
        <span class="item-name">Mela</span>
        <span class="description">12</span>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the result.
[item-image](http://sugamparajuli.com.np/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/ice_screenshot_20190107-212715.png)